# Filling form using PUT method and cURL

Tags: forms, automation, header, put, autofill

I need to fill form and then send data to the server. To simulate form filling and button submit I'm trying to use PUT method and cURL but without any success.
I have no idea what im doing wrong becouse I'm not very experienced in using cURL. Thanks to all for any help.

These headers I can see when I submit form manualy: http://www.krafty.cz/headers.txt

and here is my code:

```
$data = array(
'authenticity_token' => 'uGjjg9Jv4E5s4FE9e6afza9v1ycIR9sdAAnvmjcGf8YeUl0+UzpsaT5p/I/LIFs/kbOb7g4TmWx5Pq+TGt7V1Q==',
'show_preview' => '1',
'product[international]' => '0',

// *** THERE IS MUCH MORE FIELDS IN ARRAY HERE, ACCORDING TO HEADERS

'product[auto_renewable]' => 'true',
'button' => ''
); 

$curl = curl_init('http://en.dawanda.com/seller/products/new');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded','authenticity_token:   uGjjg9Jv4E5s4FE9e6afza9v1ycIR9sdAAnvmjcGf8YeUl0+UzpsaT5p/I/LIFs/kbOb7g4TmWx5Pq+TGt7V1Q=='));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
```